# How i can run Ghost Script command

Tags: c#, web-applications, ghostscript

How i can run the following command to convert pdf to jpeg in web application using ghost script.

I am using the following code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = @"C:\pdf\p_o6GEE+.pdf";
        string image = @"C:\image";

        try
        {
            PdfToJpg(file, image);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void PdfToJpg(string inputPDFFile, string outputImagesPath)
    {
        string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.09\bin\gswin32.exe";
        String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -o" + outputImagesPath + "%d.jpg -sPAPERSIZE=a4 " + inputPDFFile;
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

    }
```

When i try to run this code my application come in waiting state and image folder still empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use **[Ghostscript.NET](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com)** ( a wrapper for the Ghostscript library ) instead of calling .exe directly.

There you can find **GhostscriptJpegDevice** class which will do exactly what you need. Take a look at [**GhostscriptDevice usage sample**](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/DeviceUsageSample.cs)

You can also take a look at **[GhostscriptProcessor sample](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ghostscript.NET/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/ProcessorSample.cs)** which can also do what you need.

Comment: It is really working like a charm...One problem is still there how i can find the total number of pages from input file in
Export_First_And_Second_Pdf_Page_As_Color_Jpeg().

Comment: If you don't specify dev.Pdf.FirstPage and dev.Pdf.LastPage they will not be included and all pages will be exported. So, to export all pages from PDF document delete dev.PDF.FirstPage and dev.Pdf.LastPage lines from your code.

Comment: can i use this without installing gs909w32.exe ?

Comment: Sorry, no, it has to be installed on the machine.

Comment: So on server it will create issue for me to install this exe? How i can overcome this limitation

Answer (score 0):

### you have to use the: -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r600x600  -dNOSAFER -q  -sOutputFile=

in fact -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE   , will do the job you have expected,
enjoy it.